# Values being improperly communicated with bot and mysql database

Tags: node.js, roles, discord, discord.js

So I'm working on a command that allows you to spend points to rank up. These points are stored in a table called 'points', in a database with the same. Each row contains the user's discord snowflake ID, and how many points they have.

Expectation when you run for example !rankup : Checks what level you are(everyone is 0 right now, and then subtracts 100 points from the database(if you have them) and assigns you the new role of Level 1.

Outcome: Points aren't being subtracted and I'm getting this error thrown :

```
    (node:10784) DeprecationWarning: Collection#find: pass a function instead
(node:10784) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Value must be specified.
    at Map.find (C:\github\discordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\Collection.js:499:45)
    at Object.module.exports.run (C:\github\discordBot\cmds\rankup.js:12:29)
    at Client.bot.on (C:\github\discordBot\index.js:77:17)
    at Client.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\github\discordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\github\discordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:103:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\github\discordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\github\discordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\github\discordBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
(node:10784) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:10784) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
null OkPacket {
  fieldCount: 0,
  affectedRows: 1,
  insertId: 0,
  serverStatus: 34,
  warningCount: 0,
  message: '(Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0',
  protocol41: true,
  changedRows: 1 } undefined
```

Heres the code for the entire command :

```
    const Discord = module.require("discord.js");
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {


    let toPromote = message.author;

    if(message.member.roles.find("Level 0")){ //level 0
        con.query(`SELECT * FROM points WHERE id = '${toPromote.id}'`, (err, rows) =>{ //get points from database
        if(err) throw err;

        let sql;

        if(rows.length > 1) { //Has points
             //previous points found
            let points = rows[0].points;
            if(points > 100){ //has more than 100 points
                sql  = `UPDATE points SET points = ${points - 100} WHERE id = '${toPromote.id}'`; //subtract 100 points
                toPromote.removeRole(level0); //change their roles
                toPromote.addRole(level1); //change their roles
            }


        }
        con.query(sql, console.log);
    });


    }else if(message.member.roles.find("Level 2")){ //level 1

    }else if(message.member.roles.find("Level 3")){ //level 2

    }else if(message.member.roles.find("Level 4")){ //level 3

    }else if(message.member.roles.find("Level 5")){ //level 4

    }else{ //no level role, assign them one(make it if it doesn't exist)


        if(!level0) {
            try{
                role = await message.guild.createRole({
                    name: "Level 0",
                    color: "#000000",
                    permission: []
                });
            } catch(e) {
                console.log(e.stack);
            }
        }

        toPromote.addRole(level0);
    }
};
module.exports.help = {
    name: "rankup"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Roles and Permissions](https://anidiots.guide/understanding/roles) you're supposed to check for permissions like this:

```
if(message.member.roles.has(role.id)) {

}
```

You're passing a string into the `.find` method, the error that's thrown also tells you that you should pass a function into that method instead. But the `.has` function is supposed to be used to check for user roles.

Comment: Thanks I was able to get through that so it is successfully identifying the role and if the user has it. Now it's just not communicating with the mysql database. The code is still the same inside the if statement at the top but its throwing this error https://pastebin.com/Ew7K3Zu2. The other commands that interact with the database do not have this issue.

Comment: That error means that you've not defined your connection `con`, where is that defined if at all?

Comment: It's defined above as `const mysql = require("mysql");

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "1234",
    database: "points"
});`

but after running a few times it's not responding with an error saying the query is empty.

Comment: So the error is fixed now that it cannot find `con`?

Comment: Con is successfully defined, and it can find it, now It's just spitting an error that the query is empty.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe it's complaining about you're use of quotation marks around the query being `\`` and not `'` or `"`? In the formatting of stackoverflow it does not appear as string.

Comment: Heres a screenshot of what it looks like so you can see the formatting. It's exactly how my other con.queries are setup. https://i.gyazo.com/212e80b992b93fc56b4d5ab2b398c632.png

Comment: Maybe the `WHERE id = ` actually returns no results? What does it return when you try it manually in sql.

Comment: Is `rows.length` actually greater than `1`? Otherwise `let sql;` will never get a value.

Comment: Theres multiple roles, each row does indeed have an ID and point value. I entered the queries manually with specific ID's so you may be right the id isn't getting returned correctly. But when I ran the command with console.log(toPromote,id); right before the query it returned my id correctly.

Comment: If you assign your query to a variable and print that out, what's actually in the query?

Comment: Heres what gets shot out, starting with my ID, the query, then the error code following.https://pastebin.com/Xa5f8TtS

Comment: I believe your error is here though: `con.query(sql, console.log);` is `sql` actually not empty? It can only be not empty if it was set inside your if statement. I suggest just calling that `query` function directly in your if statement.

Comment: Moving the `con.query(sql, console.log);` into the if statement fixed all errors, but it's not removing the 100 points or editing roles for some reasaon

Comment: Is the if statement `points > 100` actually working? is `points` really more than `100`?

Comment: Yeah, the corresponding ID has over 300.

Comment: In your `has` function you're checking for role `level0.id` and in the `removeRole` you're trying to remove `level0`. Should that not also be `level0.id`?

Comment: The outcome is still the same, no  role change or point subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, when using `.find()` you should use this:

```
<collection>.find(c => c.<property> == 'thing');
```

When you look for a role in a server, for example, use this:

```
guild.roles.find(r => r.name == 'roleName');
```

Of course you can pass anything in the function, this is just an example.